# Bootstrapping Angular on HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've struggled to find any good documentation surrounding this. Although I've seen this done, if I'm not mistaken it was with AngularJS.

My question is, how can I bootstrap or initiate Angular on the HTML element rather than say the de facto standard `app-root` component?

Reason being is, I'm building a multilingual site, and I need to set a constant which will serve to render my components in the specified language.

If I was using another stack, I might declare a constant and then render the string accordingly.

```
// A simple dummed down example
APP_LANG: string = 'en'; // Declared somewhere globally, accessible to all modules and components.
documentTitle = {en: 'Hello', fr: 'Bonjour'};
...
// Then somewhere in my template, using string interpolation... I can set my lang attribute,
<html lang="{{APP_LANG}}">
// I can print variables using string interpolation, etc.
<title>{{documentTitle[appLang]}}</title>
```

I know I could create methods and traverse the DOM to replace the title but it seems like a hodgepodge workaround.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title)?

Comment: @CristianTraìna I had not, thanks for sharing.